# How do I access a public function outside of the view it is in using Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, function, view, mxml

**Hi, I have been working on a Flex Mobile application using Flash Builder 4.6.**

I have 2 mxml 'views' in my project. In one mxml file, i have a function that grabs xml data.
In my other mxml file, I have a refresh button that when depressed is suppsosed to call the function in the first mxml file in order to once again grab the xml data.
I dont know how to call that function from outside the mxml file it is housed in.

I appreciate any help given. Thank you!

[UPDATE #2]***

I thought I should share some more details about my issue.

1. It is a reddit client mobile app. It fetches the feeds, etc.
2. In my main view called RedditReaderHomeView.mxml, I am using a splitViewNavigator spark component to house two other views like so:

**RedditReaderHomeView.mxml**

```
    <s:SplitViewNavigator width="100%" height="100%" id="splitViewNavigator" autoHideFirstViewNavigator="true">
        <s:ViewNavigator id="redditList" firstView="views.subredditList" width="300" height="100%"/>
        <s:ViewNavigator id="redditFeed" firstView="views.redditFeed" width="100%" height="100%">

            <s:actionContent.landscape>
                <s:Button id="refreshButtonlLandscape" icon="@Embed('assets/refresh160.png')" click="refreshRSS()" />
            </s:actionContent.landscape>

            <s:actionContent.portrait>
                <s:Button id="refreshButton" icon="@Embed('assets/refresh160.png')"  />
                <s:Button id="navigatorButton" label="Search" click="splitViewNavigator.showFirstViewNavigatorInPopUp(navigatorButton)" />
            </s:actionContent.portrait>
        </s:ViewNavigator>
    </s:SplitViewNavigator>
```

1. As you can see in the code above, in my main view I have a button with the id "refreshButton." When I click this button, I want the reddit data to refresh. In other words I want to call a function to refresh the data, that is housed in the view, 'redditFeed'.
2. **This is the function which is in a separate view named 'redditFeed.mxml', that I want to call using the refresh button in the main view shown above.**

**redditFeed.mxml**

```
    protected function myList_creationCompleteHandler(url:String):void
            {

                getRedditFeedResult.token = redditFeedGrabber.getRedditFeed(url);
                getRedditFeedResult.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,busyOff);

            }
```

I hope this helped clear out confusion as to what I was trying to do. Im assuming that the solution is quite simple, but alas, I am a novice programmer and new to Flex, so Im learning the ropes. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your code is not clear. Is your SplitViewNavigator in the same file as the myList component that the function above is from, or not? It doesn't look to be the root tag of its own MXML file, since it has no namespace declaration. Can you post a larger code block that shows the relationship?

Comment: okay i clarified a bit above. Let me know if you need any more, I just didnt want to clutter the post with too much code.

Comment: Thank you both for your help on this. I have got it working now, but I have run across a new problem, which I have just submitted a new question about. Possibly one of you might be able to assist me on that as well? thanks once again for putting up with my amateurity, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have an instance of the view, then just do:

```
myViewInstance.myPublicFunction();
```

In MXML, the id element of the MXML tag is used to reference the view in ActionScript.  Since you didnt' describe your architecture; it is unclear how one view can call the other.

If the view that needs to trigger the call is a parent of the view that has the function to make the call, then you could use the approach described above.

If the view that need to trigger the call is a child of the view that has the function to make the call, then you should dispatch an event from the "child" which the parent can listen to.  In the event handler you would trigger the call.

If the view that needs to trigger and the view that has the function to make the call are both children of the same parent; then you should dispatch an event from the "Trigger" view, listen for it in the parent, and then use that event listener to make the call (Using similar code to what I explained above).

If you have a more complicated architecture of these two views; then you should look into some method to encapsulate the "remote call" functionality, such as into a service class.  Many frameworks offer approaches to share that service class and/or results across multiple classes.  ( MXML Files are classes).

Comment: well...  i will describe to you my architecture perhaps. I have my mainview. Within that view i have 2 views that are sortof embedded into a splitview navigation. So the main view houses 2 views, if you get wat i mean. The 2 views im talking about are the main view mentioned above, and 1 of the views housed within it. The one housed within is the view that contains the function, which i need to call in the mxml file of the main view. Based on this, could you please describe how I would 'dispatch' an event? I'm a young programmer and new to flex. Thank you so much for your response though.

Comment: Share some code.  Possibly edit your question to include a description of the hierarchy also. IF the main view needs to access one of it's children, use the approach I described in code as part of my answer.  Events are always dispatched up the hierarchy, never down.

Comment: Alright, I was able to get it working using the original code above. Rather stupid on my part, though I was unclear as to what you referred to by 'myViewInstance', and i didnt know that an instance of an object simply was its id in flex. Thanks you though. Also, I would upvote your post but i do not have the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this without getting into bad architecture by having the child view explicitly know about its parent:

1. Your child view can generate an event, which the parent is listening for. The parent will then call the function
2. The child view can have a public property of type Function. The parent view passes a reference to that function by setting the variable. The child view then calls the function (after checking to make sure it is not null).

Comment: with the update above, could you please reanalyze my problem and hopefully tell me how i can do it? thanks!